# "has Stopped working" message after IL Assembly editing

Tags: reverse-engineering, .net-assembly, ngen, dnspy

I am using "dnSpy" application to read and change .net assembly exe module, I chose "Edit IL Instructions..." like that
[image]

Then I change "brtrue" to "brfalse" as this picture
[image]

Then I saved a module like that 
[image]
Then I run NGRN like that
[image]
Now When I test the exe application I face "Stopped Working" message as soon as I open it 
[image]

Please Help

Comment: is it failing only after ngen? What is the reason of the crash?

Comment: It failing before and after ngen, I can't understand the reason of crash, Is there any tool that diagnostic exe crash resons?

Comment: If it crashes before `ngen` then debug in dnSpy. Or it crashes even before dnSpy takes the control? If that the case look in Events for an entry with a reason for this crash. Alternatively configure WER to collect a dump of the crash.